# Unable to create a google meet link in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have an ASP.NET Web API project and I am trying to use my email to generate a Google meet link. I created a service account and downloaded the json key.

My code is:

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
   {
       string calendarId = @"my-email";

       string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };

       ServiceAccountCredential credential;

       using (var stream =
           new FileStream(credentials, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
       {
           var confg = Google.Apis.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Instance.Deserialize<JsonCredentialParameters>(stream);
           credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
              new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(confg.ClientEmail)
              {
                  Scopes = Scopes
              }.FromPrivateKey(confg.PrivateKey));
       }

       var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
       {
           HttpClientInitializer = credential,
           ApplicationName = "Calendar API Sample",
       });

       Event newEvent = new Event()
       {
           Summary = "Test Event",
           Location = "Online",
           Start = new EventDateTime()
           {
               DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
               TimeZone = "Asia/Colombo",
           },
           End = new EventDateTime()
           {
               DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2),
               TimeZone = "Asia/Colombo",
           },
           ConferenceData = new ConferenceData()
           {
               ConferenceSolution = new ConferenceSolution()
               {
                   Key = new ConferenceSolutionKey()
                   {
                       Type = "hangoutsMeet",
                   },
               },
           },
       };

       // Insert the event and get the event ID and Hangouts Meet link
       EventsResource.InsertRequest request = service.Events.Insert(newEvent, calendarId);
       request.ConferenceDataVersion = 1;

       Event createdEvent = request.Execute();

       return Ok(createdEvent);
   }
```

but

```
Event createdEvent = request.Execute();
```

always throws a http 404 - not found error. Not any more description - I tried debugging. Just http 404 - not found.

Can someone help please?